# browserless and functionnal tests with puppeeter from container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, puppeteer

I have one container docker running browserless and another container running functionnal tests with puppeeter on the same docker compose file. Functionnals test are in a project repository and running with node 15. This docker compose is running on a server, different from my pc, and there is a dns (i don't use ip directly).

When i run the functionnals test from my pc, or from another server the test passes (functionnals tests connect to the container where is browserless running)
But when i run the test inside the dedicated container docker with the functionnals tests inside, the tests always fails at the middle.

Test steps are the following:

```
  1 connect to browserless (ok)
  2 go to specific page (ok)
  3 simulate user click (ok)
  4 simulate user typing data (ok)
  5 simulate user typing data (ok)
  6 simulate user submit (ok)
  7 go to smtp4dev , another specific page (fake smtp) (ok)
  8 simulate user opening its email (ok)
  9 found the link confirmation and click on it (ok on my pc but not from the container)
```

On the last step, i simulate user click on the last mail, then i look for an iframe where i can find the confirmation link. But here is the problem. If i run the test inside the container, the iframe is never found, but i if do from my pc or another remote server on same network, there is no problem, the iframe is always found.

I don't know what is the difference from running the test inside the container and from my pc. I don't know here i have to look.

Here is the dockerfile for my functionnals tests

```
FROM node:15

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY tools.js .
COPY subscription_test.js .
COPY password_test.js .
COPY tests.js .
CMD [ "node", "tests.js" ]
```

And the dockerfile for browserless/chrome

```
FROM browserless/chrome
USER root
RUN apt update && apt install ca-certificates libnss3-tools ffmpeg -y && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
ADD mik3fly.internal-cacert.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mik3fly.internal-cacert.crt
RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mik3fly.internal-cacert.crt && update-ca-certificates
RUN certutil -d sql:/root/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n certnickname -i /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mik3fly.internal-cacert.crt
RUN certutil -A -n certnickname -t "TCu,Cu,Tu" -i /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mik3fly.internal-cacert.crt -d sql:/root/.pki/nssdb
```

here the dockercompose config about the browserless part

```
  integration:
    image: 4steri5k/integration:${TAG}
    environment:
      - DEFAULT_IGNORE_HTTPS_ERRORS=true
      - DEFAULT_LAUNCH_ARGS=["--window-size=1920,1080","--ignore-certificate-errors"]
      - ENABLE_DEBUGGER=false
      - MAX_CONCURRENT_SESSIONS=10
      - CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=180000
      - "PROXY_HOST=vm3.mik3fly.internal/browserless/"
      - "PROXY_PORT=443"
      - "PROXY_SSL=true"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - browserless-network
      - nginx-network
      - rtx_ui-network
```

and here the part inside my functionnals tests to connect to browserless

```
console.log('https://vm1.mik3fly.internal/browserless/')
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
    browserWSEndpoint: 'ws://vm2.mik3fly.internal/browserless/',
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    args: ["--ignore-certificate-errors"],
    defaultViewport: {
        height: 1200,
        width: 1600,
        isMobile: false,
        isLandscape: false,
    }
})
```

then i do connect to the first page..

```
  try {

        const page1 = await browser.newPage();
        await page1.goto('https://vm0.mik3fly.internal/rtx', {
            waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"
        })
```

and after the mentionned steps below are executed

Comment: Do you rely on external services in your tests? Can they deny connection in theory? (say, your server's IP is not good for them)

Comment: i use fake smtp4dev, but, i can see in browserless sessions that the page was openned and the email was opened. Just, the iframe is not detected when the test are launch inside the container.

Comment: @Vaviloff, one thing i can do, it s to build and run the browserless container on a different os/docker engine version

Comment: Think of it this way: why was iframe not found when on the server? Something's different. Make a screenshot, dump HTML to check.

Comment: @Vaviloff finally found, but not always reproducible, execution inside docker-compose is faster than when i run functionnals tests from my pc. When i m looking for the iframe, the iframe is not present yet.
I put an async delay (1000~2000ms) and that passes.

Comment: Good find! Waiting for 1-2s may help now, but still it's more reliable wait for a selector (or any other condition with waitForFunction)